# Wordpress Navigation Menu Doesn't Accept Page

Tags: wordpress, web

I using Wordpress. I have a little problem. My problem is about the Navigation Menu.

I am going to add the menu Appearance >> Menus. When I add the "Contact Us" page on the Menus, its Ok.

[image]

But after the click "Save Menu", it doesn't accept. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question .  Is the Menu not saving in the back end ?
or Menu not displaying in the front end ?  Create  a new menu and added the menu items and check on 'RT Theme Main Navigation' .

Comment: Actually I'm not sure. But I think its not saving in the back end.

Comment: Did you try to create a new menu .And just add two pages to that menu  and check .

Comment: I added 7 page no problem. When I add one more, its not saving.

Comment: deactive the theme and try to save the menu .

Comment: I would like to mention one detail. I am using qTranslate-X plugin. When disable this plugin, it is working well.